# Проблемы с передечей POST C# через HttpWebResponse

Tags: php, c#, post

По нажатию кнопки отправляется запрос в php-скрипт. Ответ приходит, но массив в $_POST ничего не передается, хотя должно. Что не так?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = "&path=" + richTextBox1.Text;
    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(path);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/Kursach/Kursach.php");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencodged";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();
    }
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    richTextBox4.Text = responseString;
}
```

Comment: Для начала, `WebRequest` является устаревшим классом, который не стоит использовать для новых разработок (читайте документацию). Дальше из "того, что тут не так" - нет асинхронности, поставьте `async` у метода и в нужных местах используйте асинхронные задачи с `await`. Ну а вообще, вы пробовали смотреть что ваша программа отправляет на сервер? Поставьте Fiddler и отлавливайте этот запрос, вам будет в разы понятней что не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже написали в комментариях: избегайте использование устаревших классов и блокировки основного окна:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task = SendForm();
    var response = await task;
    richTextBox4.Text = response;
}

public async Task<string> SendForm()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1");
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("path", richTextBox1.Text)
        });
        var result = await client.PostAsync("/Kursach/Kursach.php", content);
        string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return resultContent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте убрать

```
stream.Flush();
stream.Close();
```